# How to position carousel indicators in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, carousel, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to move the indicators under the slider image by giving `.carousel-indicators` a `bottom: -50px;` but the indicators just disappear. Now I am guessing this has something to do with the `overflow:hidden` of the slider but I can't figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="header.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="slider2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="slider3.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="slider4.jpeg">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="slider5.jpeg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS here:

```
#slider {
    height: 350px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.carousel-indicators {
    bottom: -50px;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Setting `bottom: -50px` on `.carousel-indicators` works fine to move the indicators below the carousel, however the result is not visible because of the `overflow: hidden`, as you suspected correctly. The indicators are simply clipped, as they get out of the bounding box of the carousel.

Instead of setting the height and the overflow property of the `#slider` itself, I would suggest to fix the height via the `.carousel-item` class like as follows:

```
.carousel-item {
    height: 350px;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.carousel-indicators {
    bottom: -50px;
}
```

This is not interfering with the positioning of the indicators.

A working example is available as a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/dferenc/pen/XVoboo).

Answer (score 1):

Using this code worked for me!

```
 .carousel-indicator {
   position: relative;
   bottom: -50px;
 }
```

This pushed my indicators down just enough to get my paragraph visible.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this problem recently, but I solve it by setting the div flex-direction: column-reverse. This might be too late but I think it can help those who are encountering the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use bottom, the element needs to be positioned relative, absolute or  fixed. If it is relative positioned, the bottom property makes the element's bottom edge to move above/below its normal position.

```
.carousel-indicators {
position: absolute;
bottom: -50px;
}
```

If it already positioned correctly, bottom:-50px might move the element below visible area of the parent element #slider.
Try to remove overflow: hidden; from #slider and check where carousel-indicators will be positioned.

Comment: position absolute does not solve it, the indicators still do not show

Answer (score 0):

I tried to place this indicators at the bottom center of background image slider. Its working.

```css
.carousel-indicators{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom:150px;
  left:0px; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below and worked for me!

```
.carousel-indicators{
position: absolute;
bottom: -50px;
}
```